# open a PDF file with automatically replaced Fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I am not a programmer, but a normal user who uses Linux.

I want to use Ghostscript to DISPLAY Pdf files, not to CREATE Pdf files. (I have never used Ghostscript until now).

But I want Ghostscript to automatically replace all fonts with other fonts when I open the PDF. No matter if the fonts are embedded or not.

With which fonts should the fonts be replaced?
Answer: I want to create a list of fonts, that I want to be available for replacement.

But which of these fonts on the list should be used?
Answer: The one that best matches the metric of the font to be replaced.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get Ghostscript to do what you are asking. If a PDF file contains fonts Ghostscript will use those fonts, it will only substitute if it cannot find an embedded font.

The reason for this is simple; the font embedded in the PDF file is the **correct** font. It's Metrics are correct, and the mapping form character code to the appropriate glyph selector in the font will be correct.

It's also a non-trivial problem to select from a list of fonts the one which 'best matches the metrics of the font to be replaced'. What characteristics should be considered ? How should those be determined ?

When a font is not embedded then Ghostscript will consult its own list of fonts and CIDFonts. Both of these lists can be customised, the documentation is [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Fonts.htm#Get_fonts)

But since a substitute font is always going to be a compromise, you can't tell Ghostscript not to use the embedded fonts in a PDF. Well technically you could, by modifying the PDF interpreter, but you say you aren't a programmer, so I doubt you will want to try that.

Comment: Thank you. So it seems, that I only can get this in two steps. First: remove all embedded fonts from the PDF and save the resulting file as a copy. Now, the way is free to open it with customized fonts. Right? Is there a way to remove embedded fonts with Ghostscript?

Comment: If you remove the fonts, then yes you woudl then get substitutes. Ghostscript doesn't 'edit' PDF files, the pdfwrite device makes new PDF files from the input which is not quite the same thing. No it hsa no means for removing fonts, other than converting them to bitmaps or outlines. There is a NeverEmbed array of names, you could add all the font names from the input file and that would do the job. Very tedious to edit the list though. Why on Earth do you want to do this ? The result wll never be as good as maintaining the original fonts and very often will result in gibberish text in the file

Comment: Quote: "Why on Earth do you want to do this?" I simply want to have a PDF, that looks good, when anti-aliasing is disabled. So fonts that look bad without anti-aliasing must be replaced through fonts that look good without anti-aliasing. Maybe there would be a better tools for this purpose instead of Ghostscript?

Comment: Replacing the fonts **will** lead to metrics differences, shape differences in the glyphs, mis-positioning and in extreme cases, wrong text (due to subset fonts and re-encoding). All this because you don't like text without anti-aliasing ? Obviously its up to you. You will almost certainly haev to use multiple tools to achieve what you are after. I imagine a multitude of PDF editing tools will allow you to remove fonts (or at least remove the reference to the embedded FontFile). I doubt there's any tool which will specifically remove all embedded fotns, but I could be wrong.